# bash integer expression expected when using greater than

Tags: bash, if-statement, integer

I'm writing a script and part of it outputs a number $stats i.e 74.9 and if it's less than 100 it's a fail if not it's a pass. I've tried

```
do stuff
done

echo $stats

if [ $stats -gt 100 ]; then
echo "PASS"
else
echo "FAIL"
fi
```

but it fails with

```
72.4
./runme.sh: line 66: [: 72.4: integer expression expected
FAIL
```

Comment: Well, 72.4 isn't an integer. What's your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

72.4 is obviously not an integer.  Bash only supports integer arithmetic.

Common workarounds include:

- Truncation. `if [ ${stats%.*} -gt 100 ]; then` ...
- Proper rounding using an external tool. `if [ $(echo "$stats > 100.0" | bc) = 1 ]; then`... (There will probably be more elegant ways to express this; but it's often painful.)
- Converting to integer.  Feasible if you have a fixed number of decimals. `if [ ${stats%.*}${stats#*.} -gt 10000 ]; then`...

Comment: You'll want to use `-ge` if 100.00 is a pass.